# How to persist the inheritance classes on the EF for different types

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We have the following model mapped and working with Entity Framework:

```
abstract class Person { ... }
class Customer : Person { ... }
class Employee : Person { ... }
class Supplier : Person { ... }
```

On the database level, we have a table for each class related by ID following the the Table-per-Type configuration. It works fine!

On the business side, we have a possibility of a Customer also been an Supplier, and we would like to reuse this record on the tables. Is it possible? How can we configure and persist it?

Thank you!

Comment: What about a `class CustomerAndSupplier : Person {}`?

Comment: I am starting thinking my model is not correct. Maybe I should not use inheritance and use a single class for each `Person`. From business side, a Person could be only one of these 3 types, or 2, or all of the 3, does not matter what.

Comment: I agree that a `Customer`, `Employee` and `Supplier` can all be the same person. How about moving the class-specific properties into Info-classes, such as `CustomerInfo`, `EmployeeInfo` and `SupplierInfo` with their own tables. Make person non-abstract and its own table. Every person can have an optional relationship with a Info-entity.

Comment: Furthermore, you can have a `Customer`, `Employee` and `Supplier` class on the business side. You just to need to create a custom mapping strategy. Then you could for example get one or multiple Suppliers by fetching Person entities from the database that has a foreign key for a SupplierInfo entity, then map these Person entities to your business Supplier-type.

Comment: If a customer *can* also be a supplier, that's incidental. It doesn't sound like a good reason for an inheritance relationship between the two.

Comment: Yes, it is not possible from the EF perspective to have this model I need well-hydrated. I think @ThomasAngeland solution is a good one and I will try to follow something like this. Thank you guys!

Comment: And by simply not mapping the Person entity, you'll get 3 unrelated tables in the database that share a base class in .NET.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I think this way it would duplicate information =/

Comment: You could also have a seperate Person or BusinessEntity table like in AdventureWorks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=ssms